# React google map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps

I want to render two google map in one page. In First map I want to create some areas like polygons and edit it, and then into second map I want to display all available areas but not edit it. It's possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, absolutely Yes. It's possible my friend.